# How does HQ work in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I'm unsure how to be effective in HQ games, how exactly does that mode work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture and hold a control point of three on a map. The longer you hold, the more points your team gets. The game ends either on the maximum score of 9000 or after the time runs out, the team with the higher score wins. A default match duration of 15 minutes is assumed.

See [Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Headquarters) for details.

Comment: Also, once your team captures the HQ you won't re-spawn immediately after death. There is a delayed re-spawn timer.

Comment: Actually, you won't respawn at all, if you get killed after your team captures the HQ. After the HQ is destroyed or becomes offline, you can respawn.